# Property of the function $u(t)$ satisfying the convolution equation $z(t) = u(t)*[0.5t + (t-1)H(t-1)]$ with boundary conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution, integral-equations

I have the following convolution equation:

$$
z(t) = u(t)*[0.5t + (t-1)H(t-1)], \ t \in [0\ 5],
$$
where **both functions $z(t)$ and $u(t)$ are unknown**, $H(.)$ is the unit Heaviside function, and $*$ is the convolution operator. Moreover, the function $z(t)$ must satisfy the boundary conditions:

$$
z(5) = 1, \ \dot{z}(5) = 0.
$$

My goal is: **I would like to design the function $u(t)$ that satisfies the defined boundary values of $z(t)$.**

It seems not difficult if we assume a special form of $u(t)$  (e.g. $a\sin(\omega t)$) and compute the parameters $a$ and $\omega$ by using the given boundary conditions of $z(t)$.

However, I would like to generalize the class of functions that $u(t)$ should belong to rather than a specific case.

So my question is: **What are the special properties of $u(t)$ could we exploit from the above conditions? Or what tools we can use here?**

I very much appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Using the Laplace transform we have

$$
Z(s) = U(s)\frac{2 e^{-s}+1}{2 s^2}
$$

now making

$$
U(s) = \frac as+\frac{b}{s^2}+\frac{c}{s^3}\Rightarrow Z(s) = \left( \frac as+\frac{b}{s^2}+\frac{c}{s^3}\right)\frac{2 e^{-s}+1}{2 s^2}
$$

and after anti transforming we obtain

$$
z(t) = \frac{1}{48} \left(2 (t-1)^2 H(t-1) (12 a+(t-1) (4 b+c (t-1)))+t^2 (12 a+t (4 b+c t))\right)
$$

The determination of $a, b, c$ follows with the initial conditions:

$$
z(5) = 1\ \ \ z'(5) =0
$$

giving

$$
a = \frac{61609 c}{38028}\\
b = -\frac{14061 c}{6338}
$$

This procedure can be applied for any set of $u(t)$ Laplace transformable functions.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer @Cesareo! According to your answer, I understood that the class of n-order time polynomial functions can do the job. But we can also use other elementary functions such as trigonometric, or hyperbolic, or piece-wise continuous, etc. function classes to solve the question. My main goal is to determine the most general properties for which every function class has to possess. Is it possible? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I wrote that any set of $u(t)$ Laplace transformable functions conveniently combined can be used. Those functions include the elementary functions $1,t^n, \cos a t,\sin a t, e^{b t}, \cdots$ etc.

Comment: Alright. Thanks!